# Using host's iptables to prevent access to docker-container's exposed ports

Tags: iptables, nat, docker, containers, dnat

I have a host which runs a few docker's containers.

This host has a few network interfaces, my goal is make some exposed ports from containers accessible only by certain interfaces, and prevent access from others.

I would like to use host's iptables for that.

But its imposible to do simply with:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i vlan2 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

because packets are forwarded by prerouting.

```
iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING                                                                                                                               2
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql to:172.17.0.2:33066
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:172.17.0.4:80
```

There are two exposed ports 80 and 3306 to different containers, and I want to make it inaccessible from interface vlan2

After I added this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i vlan2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Web server stopped to work, but

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i vlan2 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT
```

don't prevent connection to mysql, I am still able to connect.
And tcpdump proves it:

```
tcpdump -n -i vlan2 port 3306
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on vlan2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:48:13.066636 IP 3.2.2.2.47259 > 1.1.2.3.3306: Flags [S], seq 3619220560, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 90183390 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:48:13.066740 IP 1.1.2.3.3306 > 3.2.2.2.47259: Flags [S.], seq 2743923517, ack 3619220561, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10989883 ecr 90183390,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

And I can't understand the difference between these two rules.

How to use host's iptables to prevent access to containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your NAT rule in the `PREROUTING` chain of the nat table translates host's port **`3306`** to `172.17.0.2:`**`33066`** and not to `172.17.0.2:`**`3306`** thus the rule in the `FORWARD` chain of the filter table doesn't match anything since it tries to drop traffic forwarded to destination port **`3306`**.